# Access fields in class

Tags: java, android

My project consists of some classes: type 1 and type 2 and ... is that each has its own functions and fields I'm gonna use them as follows:

```
  public interface iType {
    public void initialize();
  }

  public class Type1 implements iType {
    public static final String GROUP = "F1";
    public String[][] arrayName = new String[][]{
      {"a1", "d1"},
      {"b1", "f1"},
      {"c1", "g1"},
    };
    public HashMap<String, Unit> mapName = new HashMap<String, Unit>();

    @Override
    public void initialize() {
      //initialize Hashmap
    }
  }

  public class Type2 implements iType {
    public static final String GROUP = "F2";
    public String[][] arrayName = new String[][]{
      {"a2", "d2"},
      {"b2", "f2"},
      {"c2", "g2"},
    };
    public HashMap<String, Unit> mapName = new HashMap<String, Unit>();

    @Override
    public void initialize() {
      //initialize Hashmap
    }
  }

  //other classes : Type3 ,Type4 ,...

  private iType modify(String type) {
    switch (type) {
      case "Type1":
        return new Type1();
      case "Type2":
        return new Type2();
      /*
      case "Type3":
        .
        .
        .
      */
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void main() {
    iType x = modify(getType());
    ((Type1) x).
  }
```

In this case can not be used to cast : `((Type?)x).arrayName`

I do not want to cast because i do not know which class in the variable x is, So how do I cast the variable x ? The value of x is dependent on the getType()

How do I access the fields classes through x ?

Comment: You could add the getters of the common variables in the interface `iType`, then is not need any casting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I access the fields classes through x ?

You could add a new method to `iType`,

```
 public String[][] getNames();
```

both `Type1` and `Type2` will be forced to implement it. Let this method return your array. This way you will avoid the cast